# Marchingcube planet vegetation; Large amount of meshes performance

Tags: three.js

I would like to inquire some insights into rendering a large amount of meshes with the best performance.

[image: planet preview from space]

I'm working on generative mine-able planets incorporating marching cube chunked terrain. Currently I'm trying to add vegetation/rocks to spruce up the planet surfaces (get it?). I am using the actual chunk loading to (next to the terrain) also load smaller rocks and some grass stuff. That runs pretty well. I am having issues with tree's and boulders (visible on the entire planet surface but LODed, obviously).

Testing different methods have lead me on the road of;

- Custom shaders with material clipping based on camera distance; Works okay for about half a million trees made from 2 perpendicular planes (merged into one single bufferGeometry). But those 'models' are not good enough.
- THREE.LOD's; Which sucks up fps like crazy, to slow for large amounts of meshes.
- THREE.InstancedMesh's; Works pretty well, however I'd have to disable frustumCulling, since the originpoint of the vegetation is not always on screen. Which makes it inefficient.
- THREE.InstancedGeometry combined with the custom clipping shaders; I had high hopes for this, it gives the best performance while using actual models. But it still eats up half of the frameRate. The vertexshader still has to process all the vertices to determine if it is within clipping range. Also the same frustumCulling issue applies.
- Material.clippingPlanes? Combined with InstancedMeshes; This is what I'm trying now, did not have any luck with it, still trying to figure out exactly how that works..

Does anyone have experience with rendering large amounts of meshes or has some advice for me? Is there a technique I do not yet know about?

Would it help to split up the trees in multiple InstancedMeshes? Would the clippingPlanes give me better performance?

Comment: rendering half a million trees sounds like the first place to start. half a million trees, there are only ~2 million pixels on a 1920x1080 screen. Rendering half a million trees seems like the wrong approach. How about changing what you're actaully rendering, for example your screenshot, it seems like you should just be rendering a texture that has spots for vegation at best.

Comment: Good point. I am not trying to render all trees, the trees on the backside of the planet wouldn't be visible anyway. This question is more about how to cut down the amount of visible trees rendered. Initializing that many tree models doesn't seem to be a problem (if i enable frustumCulling it still runs at 60fps when not looking at them), but rendering all of them is quite impossible. Your approach of a vegetation spot texture is interesting. Your saying I would have to check how far the camera is from those spots and generate them on the fly? Wouldn't that affect performance more, using js?:)